# How to kill the screen recording "Start" dialog

Tags: video-recording

After starting the Screen Recording app the "Start" dialog with the red circle is now always there. How can the app and that icon be closed?

This is Android9 on an Xiaomi Redmi 8A

Comment: Which Recording app are you talking about exactly?

Comment: Record screen accessible by swiping down twice and then swipe left twice

Comment: If this is not a 3rd-party app, probably worth also mentioning the device model and Android version since not all Android devices have in-built screen recording :)

Answer (score 0):

The Start/red circle does have an X on it. I had tried it a number of times and nothing happened.  Now I tried it again and it did close the recorder (after a confirmation dialog).  Not sure why it is so difficult to accept the click.